# How to give transition effects to dynamically changing image backgrounds using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page wherein the background image for a particular div keeps changing dynamically. I wanna be able to give some transition effects on the images. The page runs on pure javascript. Here's my code:

```
var bgArray = ["images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg"];
var i = 0;

function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (i == 3) {
            i = 0;
        }
        var urlString = bgArray[i];
        var x = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        x.style.background = "url(" + bgArray[i] + ") no-repeat";
        x.style.backgroundSize = "1366px";
        i = i + 1;
    }, 6000);
}

myFunction();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#myDiv {
  transition: background 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML code

```
<div id = "myDiv"></div>
```

CSS code

```
#myDiv{
   width: <yourDivWidth>;
   height: <yourDivHeight>;
   background-size: cover;
  }
```

Javascript code

```
var box = document.getElementById("myDiv");    
var imagesList = ["url('images/1.jpg')", "url('images/2.jpg')", "url('images/3.jpg')"];

i = 0;
box.style.backgroundImage = imagesList[i];

function nextImg(){
   box.style.backgroundImage = imagesList[i+1];
   //box.style.width = "1366px";
   //box.style.height = "1366px";
   //declare your width and height of div in css and give background-size: cover;.
   i = i+1;
   if(i == imagesList.length){
     i = 0;
     box.style.backgroundImage = imagesList[i];
   }
}

window.onload = setInterval(nextImg, 6000);
```

Wait for 6 sec and see the background images changing.
If you want to set background image for the first 6sec also, then you can set that in your CSS.
Comment if u have any doubts.